# What is an exception in ARM?

Tags: exception, arm, interrupt

Good day!

I am currently studying [AArch64 Exception Handling](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/CEGIDCIC.html).

At the beginning of the document is written:

> Strictly speaking, an interrupt is something that interrupts the flow of software execution. However, in ARM terminology, that is actually an exception.

This means that interrupts are an exception for ARM, right?

I do not have fluency in English, so I have a lot of trouble reading the documents.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just think of interrupts as one kind of exception.

Comment: @PaulR
Thank you.
If so, is the interrupt implemented as an exception in ARM? Or are they just trying to think of interrupts as a kind of exception?

Comment: I'm not an expert on ARM, but I expect that the exception handling mechanism is common to both interrupts and other types of exception.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

ARM and many other architectures consider the interrupts as a subset of exceptions, because as you cited, all of the exceptions are able to interrupt the flow of software execution (not only interrupts). Summarising, all interrupts are exceptions, but not all exceptions are interrupts, given that, some exceptions can be (managed by an exception handler through a [vector table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/CHDEEDDC.html)):

- Reset, the highest priority exception
- Undefined instruction
- Interrupts (managed by an interrupt handler): FIQ, IRQ (FIQs priority is higher than IRQs) or SWI
- Aborts, data or prefetch
- ...

So an unaligned data access (data abort) and a timer (IRQ) will trigger the exception handler (and halt the "expected execution of the instructions"), but a data abort is not an interrupt, is an exception.

Comment: This means that interrupts are considered a subset of exceptions, not just ARM but also in normally?

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: It's known as a 'unified exception model'.  The design aim was to simplify the configuration and handling of interrupts and 'traditional' exceptions (exceptional CPU states) by using the same handler model for everything.  It worked, IMO.

Comment: Nice comment, I didn't know about this definition.